# Testing React Component w/ Enzyme Depends on Head/Meta Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, enzyme, react-rails

I am trying to test a component that requires a `meta` tag in the `head` of the HTML page.

The reason it requires this is because it is a `rails` application and uses `react-rails-form-helpers` to render the form with the CSRF token which it takes from the HTML `head`.

Is there anyway I can mock this data in the head or insert it using `enzyme` so that I can `mount` the react component?